# How do I ask "dig" to only return the IP from a CNAME record?

Tags: dig

The `dig +short` command (such as described in "[dig show only answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/431080/dig-show-only-answer)") is great for batch processing names into IP addresses. It does a simple job and does it well.

Unfortunately when there's a CNAME even `+short` isn't short enough. For example:

```
$ dig +short docs.sbonds.org
ghs.google.com.
173.194.69.121
```

I've tried `+noall` but it doesn't seem like it changes the behavior of `+short`. I've also tried specifying `-t a` just to ensure it didn't think I meant an A record or CNAME, but that (unsurprisingly) changes nothing.

```
$ dig +noall +short docs.sbonds.org
ghs.google.com.
173.194.69.121
```

I'm using RedHat 7's `dig`:

```
# dig -v
DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-73.el7_6
```

I can filter out the CNAMEs with trusty `grep`, but it seems like dig should have some way to give "Just the IP, ma'am."

What is that way?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`dig` is a troubleshooting tool, so it sends DNS queries and receives DNS answers and as Andreas said the answer is both CNAME and A records, as designed. Your wish is to give "Just the IP, ma'am.", so that is not a DNS troubleshooting, it is "just" the resolution, for which `dig` is too much.

## nslookup

`nslookup` is inferior to `dig` but will still give you too much:

```
$ nslookup docs.sbonds.org
Server:     192.0.2.254
Address:    192.0.2.254#53

Non-authoritative answer:
docs.sbonds.org canonical name = ghs.google.com.
Name:   ghs.google.com
Address: 172.217.4.179
```

## host

`host` is simpler but will still return "too much" for you (but note that it returns also the IPv6 address which is good):

```
$ host docs.sbonds.org
docs.sbonds.org is an alias for ghs.google.com.
ghs.google.com has address 172.217.15.83
ghs.google.com has IPv6 address 2607:f8b0:4004:815::2013
```

## getent

Depending on your Unix system, `getent` can be used. Note however that this may or may not do a DNS query because you configure in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` the source of data per service, and for `hosts` it will probably be a mix of both `files` (which is the venerable `/etc/hosts`) and the DNS.

```
$ getent hosts docs.sbonds.org
2607:f8b0:4007:801::2013 ghs.google.com docs.sbonds.org
```

Observe also that on a proper Unix setup it will favor IPv6 over IPv4 so that may be a problem for you (this should depend on the configuration in `/etc/gai.conf`)

In fact `hosts` does not honor `/etc/gai.conf`, you need to use `ahosts` instead, which will use `getaddrinfo` and hence `gai.conf`. Observe that you get a list (whose order depends on `gai.conf` configuration):

```
$ getent ahosts docs.sbonds.org
172.217.4.179   STREAM ghs.google.com
172.217.4.179   DGRAM
172.217.4.179   RAW
2607:f8b0:4007:801::2013 STREAM
2607:f8b0:4007:801::2013 DGRAM
2607:f8b0:4007:801::2013 RAW
```

## Perl

If you are allowed to write a simple script, you have many solutions, like:

```
$ perl -MSocket -E 'say inet_ntoa(inet_aton("docs.sbonds.org"))'
172.217.4.179
```

## DOH

Or use any DOH (DNS over HTTPS) endpoint (or similar) with any HTTP client. Examples:

```
$ curl --silent 'https://dns.google.com/resolve?name=docs.sbonds.org&type=A' | jq -c '.Answer[] | select(.type == 1) | .data'
"172.217.3.83"


$ curl --silent -H 'accept: application/dns-json' 'https://cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query?name=docs.sbonds.org&type=A' | jq -c '.Answer[] | select(.type == 1) | .data'
"172.217.12.147"
```

## Systemd

Systemd has its own resolver application:

```
$ systemd-resolve docs.sbonds.org
docs.sbonds.org: 172.217.9.51
                 2607:f8b0:4009:801::2013
                 (ghs.google.com)

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 239.1ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```

You still need to parse it in some way, but it does give the direct final IP addresses (there is a flag when you invoke it to make it not follow `CNAME` records for whatever use cases that need that)

Comment: "Write a simple script" is where I've always ended up before. It seemed like there must be a better way, but it looks like there is not.

Comment: @SteveBonds see my update with a DOH case (similar to)

Comment: You have no idea how much I wish "jq" was more widely installed. Nonetheless, that was an excellent addition to the solution!

Comment: Just in case this helps, this is what I end up doing: `dig +noall +answer host.example.com  | awk '/ IN A\t/ { print $5 }'`

Comment: @dossy Your solution doesn't work (because it can be a space, not a tab after `A` depending on lots of things). Try with `www.icann.org` which is a CNAME. Parsing `dig` output is never a good idea and will yield a ton of edge cases.

Comment: @PatrickMevzek You're right, it could be a tab or space, so this would be more robust: `dig +noall +answer www.icann.org | awk '/\sIN\s+A\s/ { print $5 }'`

Comment: @dossy Stop trying to parse `dig` output that is tailored for human consumption, not machine one. But if you insist on doing so, have a look at least at the `+yaml` option...

Answer (score 15):

Both the CNAME and the corresponding A (or whatever type you asked for) belong to the answer-section.
As such there is no dig option (at least not in RHEL7's dig) that could filter out the CNAME response.

I think you will have to rely on `dig +short [...] | grep -v '\.$'` to remove the CNAME responses.

Comment: Or `dig +short ... | tail -1`

Comment: not exactly. `|tail -1` will show the last line. If there is more than one address in the RRset the CNAME points to this will give the wrong result.

Comment: I agree but the user request could be understood as the IP, singular, not all :-). Indeed, whatever filtering is applied can have edge cases (filtering on end dot can fail if remote nameserver is broken in some way, like returning IP addresses there too; not supposed to happen but in DNS world everything can happen)

Comment: Sigh, it is frustrating that `dig +short -t A` will output the canonical name of a CNAME if a CNAME exists and an A record doesn't.  I would much rather it output nothing or an error message like `host` does.