# dig - get only hostnames

Tags: regex, dig

Could someone help me if there exists some way how to get from dig only hostnames if I want to get list of DNS zone? I work with this command:

```
dig @dns.example.com example.com axfr
```

output is:

```
example1.com.  1200   IN   A    1.1.1.1
example2.com.  1200   IN   A    2.2.2.2
....
```

I would like to get only

```
example1.com
example2.com
....
```

I tried to use filters `dig .... | cut -d ' ' -f1` , but it doesn't work correctly in this case. Maybe I should use some regex?

Comment: `dig +short . . . `  or check out this question https://serverfault.com/questions/431080/dig-show-only-answer?rq=1

Comment: @BrandonXavier I tried `+short` but it gives me a lot of IP address instead of names. I think the better way will be to parse it. However I don't know how to cut first column.

Comment: Your cut command looks correct. What is the problem you are having with it?

Answer (score 0):

Safe your ouput into TEST and then run this command.
It compares your output with a regex which searches for the hostname.

`[[ $TEST =~ ^([a-zA-Z1-9])*.[a-zA-Z]* ]] | echo "${BASH_REMATCH}"`

Hope this Helps

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.